# Conditionally add new tag in XML with powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have two XML files like following.

XML file 1:

```xml
<tag1>
<pmtinf>
    <srn>1111</srn>
</pmtinf>
<pmtinf>
    <srn>2222</srn>
</pmtinf>
<pmtinf>
    <srn>3333</srn>
</pmtinf>
</tag1>
```

XML file 2:

```xml
<tag2>
<inf>
    <srn>1111</srn>
    <sometag>abcdf</sometag>
</inf>
<inf>
    <srn>4444</srn>
    <sometag>zxcz</sometag>
</inf>
<inf>
    <srn>5555</srn>
    <sometag>vcxv</sometag>
</inf>
</tag2>
```

From second file I get the srn tag values and then I need to find matching srn in first file (only one matches) and add newtag in pmtinf tag of the matched srn (I need to take value of sometag and add to newtag) and save new XML. The result should be like this.

```xml
<tag1>
<pmtinf>
    <srn>1111</srn>
    <newtag> abcdf</newtag>
</pmtinf>
<pmtinf>
    <srn>2222</srn>
</pmtinf>
<pmtinf>
    <srn>3333</srn>
</pmtinf>
</tag1>
```

My code:

```bsh
# get  all srns
[xml]$XML1 = Get-Content -Path "\\XML1.xml"
# loop through XML1 file's srns
foreach ($srn1 in $XML1.tag1.pmtinf.srn) {
    # loop through XML2 files
    [xml]$XML2 = Get-Content -Path "\\XML2.xml"
    # check and find file where current SRN exists
    foreach ($srn2 in $XML2.tag2.inf|where{$_.srn -eq $srn1}) {
        $sometag = $srn2.tag2.inf.sometag

        # Here I need to add sometag as a new tag in XML file 1 and save it. But
        # I Don't know how to find exact needed pmtinf node and add <newtag>
        # there.
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the value of newtag from?

Comment: I take it from second file, I am updating the question

Comment: Is there some code you've already tried? This community is not a code writing service.

Comment: @Moerwald, I add my code to question